# How to do an unsafe addition (addition without throwing OverflowException) in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

How do I able to add `Int::MAX + 1` without getting `OverflowException`? I know I can do

```
def add_unsafe(a : Int, b : Int) : Int
    ((a.to_i128 + b.to_i128) % Int32::MAX).to_i
end
```

But is there any alternative to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for wrapping operators. Most math operators have a wrapping variant prefixed with `&`. So in your case, that would be `a &+ b`.

Btw. your example doesn't work because `to_i` still does an overflow check. So calling `add_unsafe(Int32::MAX, 1)` raises an error.
A more accurate representation of wrapping behaviour would be `(a.to_i128 + b.to_i128) % Int32::MAX`. The `&+` operator is obviously better, though.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something